# Extract characters between specified characters in R

Tags: r, string, extract, gsub

I have this variable
x= "379_exp_mirror1.csv"
I need to extract the number ("379") at the beggining (which doesn't always have 3 characters), i.e. everything before the first "*". And then I need to extract everything between the second "*" and the ".", in this case "mirror1".

I have tried several combinations with sub and gsub with no success, can anyone give me some indications please?

Thank you

Comment: First please provide reproducible example. Also look into Pattern Matching and Replacement http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html

Comment: There seem to be some missing underscores in your question..

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression. For your problem `^(?<Number>[0-9]*)_.*` do the job

1/ Test your regular expression with this website : http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Or you can split string with underscore and then try parse (int.TryParse). I think the second is better but if you want to be a regular expression master try the first method

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to extract the substrings:

```
x <- "379_exp_mirror1.csv" 

sub("_.*", "", x)
# [1] "379"

sub("^(?:.*_){2}(.*?)\\..*", "\\1", x)
# [1] "mirror1"
```

Another approach with `gregexpr`:

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr("^.*?(?=_)|(?<=_)[^_]*?(?=\\.)", x, perl = TRUE))[[1]]
# [1] "379"     "mirror1"
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try:

```
 library(stringr)
 x <- "379_exp_mirror1.csv" 
 str_extract_all(x, perl('^[0-9]+(?=_)|[[:alnum:]]+(?=\\.)'))[[1]]
 #[1] "379"     "mirror1"
```

Or

```
   strsplit(x, "[._]")[[1]][c(T,F)]
   #[1] "379"     "mirror1"
```

Or

```
    scan(text=gsub("[.]","_", x),what="",sep="_")[c(T,F)]
   #Read 4 items
   #[1] "379"     "mirror1"
```